# A = { x:x²=1, x is integer} How to get -1?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A = { x:x²=1, x is integer}

How to get -1?

The answer is -1 and 1.

1² = 1

But where -1 come from?

Comment: $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$.

Comment: $x^2=1\iff x^2-1=0\iff (x+1)(x-1)=0\iff x+1=0\vee x-1=0$

Comment: It satisfies the conditions: $(-1)^2=1$ and $-1$ is an integer. Nothing more to it.

Comment: Not sure I am following, but $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$.  Does that help?

Comment: Because $(-1)^2 = 1$ as well and $(-1)$ is an integer.

Answer (score 1):

You wish to solve the equation $x^2=1$.  You might remember that (most) quadratic equation has two solutions, since squaring removes a negative sign.

$$(-a)^2=(-a)(-a)=(a)(a)=a^2$$

This equation tells us that your equation has multiple solutions, as when we plug in $a=1$ we get

$$(-1)^2=(-1)(-1)=(1)(1)=1^2=1$$

So both $1$ and $-1$ are solutions to $x^2=1$ and so that is the answer.